# Qt Connecting Signal to Slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have two classes. For simplicity, I'll call them class A and class B. I want to use the [Qt Signals and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) to link when the functions `setXPos()` or `setYPos()` of class `A` are called to class `B` that displays an image on a certain position so that the image cna move to the correct coordinates. Here is my code:

```
class A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A();
    void setXPos(int newPos) {xPos = newPos; emit posChanged(xPos, yPos);};
    void setYPos(int newPos) {yPos = newPos; emit posChanged(xPos, yPos);};

signals:
    void posChanged(int x, int y);

private:
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
};


class B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<A> classA);
    void changePos(int x, int y);

public slots:
    void posChanged(int x, int y);

private:
    QPixmap image;
    std::shared_ptr<A> classA;
};
```

So in my `B` object I want to catch the emit of the `posChanged()` in class `A`. You can see in the constructor of `B` a pointer to `A` is given, which is stored in class `B`. So in the constructor I want to do:

```
B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> classA) : classA(classA)
{
    QObject::connect(classA, SIGNAL(posChanged(int x, int y)), *this, SLOT(posChanged(int x, int y)));
}
```

But this gives errors that there is no matching function for my call inside my `connect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use arguments in connect, only types. So try next:

```
QObject::connect(classA.get(), SIGNAL(posChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(posChanged(int, int)));
```

Comment: Is this really working? Doesn't get the object returned by classA.get() deleted when the shared_ptr does not count any reference on this object?

Answer (score 7):

I believe this should work:

```
QObject::connect(classA.get(), SIGNAL(posChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(posChanged(int, int)));
```

However, using std::shared_ptr for ownership in Qt is not the "normal" way in Qt, and will probably cause issues later. If you need one object to "own" another, it is better to use Qt's [parenting mechanism](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)